# Extracting text from a site using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried extracting some text in this [site](https://www.legit.ng/1087216-igbo-proverbs-meaning.html), but i'm stuck somewhere:

```
import  pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.legit.ng/1087216-igbo-proverbs-meaning.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

data1 = []
for i in soup.findAll('div'):
    name = i.find('blockquote')
    if name:
        data.append(name.text.split('–')[1])

        data
```

result:

```
[' Gidi gidi bụ ugwu eze.',
 ' Gidi gidi bụ ugwu eze.',
 ' Gidi gidi bụ ugwu eze.',
 ' Gidi gidi bụ ugwu eze.',
 ' Gidi gidi bụ ugwu eze.',
 ' Gidi gidi bụ ugwu eze.']
```

I only want the blockquote element having *Igbo Proverb*, not *English Meaning* in the site

Comment: in every `div` there are many `blockquote` so you should use `find_all('blockquote')`

Answer (score 0):

In every `div` there are many `blockquote` so you should use `find_all('blockquote')` to get all of them. Currenty you get only first `blockquote` from every `div`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.legit.ng/1087216-igbo-proverbs-meaning.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

data = []
for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    for block in div.find_all('blockquote'):
        text = block.text
        if text.startswith('Igbo Proverb – '):
            #name = text.split('–')[1].strip()
            name = text[15:]  # len('Igbo Proverb – ') == 15
            data.append(name)

for item in data:
    print(item)
```

Result

```
Gidi gidi bụ ugwu eze.
Otu onye tuo izu, o gbue ochu
Oge adighi eche mmadu
Ihe di woro ogori azuala na ahia.
O bulu na i taa m aru n'ike, ma i zeghi nshi; mu taa gi aru n'isi, agaghi m ezere uvulu.
Ihere adịghị eme onye ara ka ọ na-eme ụmụ-nna ya.
Nwunye awo si na di atoka uto, ya jiri nuta nke ya kworo ya n'azu.
Nwaanyi muta ite ofe mmiri mmiri, di ya amuta ipi utara aka were suru ofe.
Gidi gidi bụ ugwu eze.
Otu onye tuo izu, o gbue ochu
Oge adighi eche mmadu
Ihe di woro ogori azuala na ahia.
O bulu na i taa m aru n'ike, ma i zeghi nshi; mu taa gi aru n'isi, agaghi m ezere uvulu.
Ihere adịghị eme onye ara ka ọ na-eme ụmụ-nna ya.
Nwunye awo si na di atoka uto, ya jiri nuta nke ya kworo ya n'azu.
Nwaanyi muta ite ofe mmiri mmiri, di ya amuta ipi utara aka were suru ofe.
Gidi gidi bụ ugwu eze.
Otu onye tuo izu, o gbue ochu
Oge adighi eche mmadu
Ihe di woro ogori azuala na ahia.
O bulu na i taa m aru n'ike, ma i zeghi nshi; mu taa gi aru n'isi, agaghi m ezere uvulu.
Ihere adịghị eme onye ara ka ọ na-eme ụmụ-nna ya.
Nwunye awo si na di atoka uto, ya jiri nuta nke ya kworo ya n'azu.
Nwaanyi muta ite ofe mmiri mmiri, di ya amuta ipi utara aka were suru ofe.
Gidi gidi bụ ugwu eze.
Otu onye tuo izu, o gbue ochu
Oge adighi eche mmadu
Ihe di woro ogori azuala na ahia.
O bulu na i taa m aru n'ike, ma i zeghi nshi; mu taa gi aru n'isi, agaghi m ezere uvulu.
Ihere adịghị eme onye ara ka ọ na-eme ụmụ-nna ya.
Nwunye awo si na di atoka uto, ya jiri nuta nke ya kworo ya n'azu.
Nwaanyi muta ite ofe mmiri mmiri, di ya amuta ipi utara aka were suru ofe.
Gidi gidi bụ ugwu eze.
Otu onye tuo izu, o gbue ochu
Oge adighi eche mmadu
Ihe di woro ogori azuala na ahia.
O bulu na i taa m aru n'ike, ma i zeghi nshi; mu taa gi aru n'isi, agaghi m ezere uvulu.
Ihere adịghị eme onye ara ka ọ na-eme ụmụ-nna ya.
Nwunye awo si na di atoka uto, ya jiri nuta nke ya kworo ya n'azu.
Nwaanyi muta ite ofe mmiri mmiri, di ya amuta ipi utara aka were suru ofe.
Gidi gidi bụ ugwu eze.
Otu onye tuo izu, o gbue ochu
Oge adighi eche mmadu
Ihe di woro ogori azuala na ahia.
O bulu na i taa m aru n'ike, ma i zeghi nshi; mu taa gi aru n'isi, agaghi m ezere uvulu.
Ihere adịghị eme onye ara ka ọ na-eme ụmụ-nna ya.
Nwunye awo si na di atoka uto, ya jiri nuta nke ya kworo ya n'azu.
Nwaanyi muta ite ofe mmiri mmiri, di ya amuta ipi utara aka were suru ofe.
```